# What are the HSK3.0 measure words as per the textbook 《汉语国际教育用词语声调组合及轻重音格式实用手册》?

Tags: measure-word, hsk

**Question**: What are the HSK3.0 measure words?

I went through the book 汉语国际教育用词语声调组合及轻重音格式实用手册 by 刘英林 [ed.] (considered the likely candidate for the upcoming HSK3.0 vocabulary) and inspected what was classed as "量" (measure word).  I list them as a self-answer.

(*Edit*: the above textbook does not precisely coincide with [the official standards](http://www.moe.gov.cn/jyb_xwfb/gzdt_gzdt/s5987/202103/W020210329527301787356.pdf); see [What is known about the new HSK 3.0 (2021) format?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39643/8099.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I haven't missed any, the following are the 141 measure words (or classifiers) from the aforementioned book.  They're sorted according to frequency based on the [LWC corpus](http://lwc.daanvanesch.nl/help.php).  The definitions are mostly from CC-CEDICT (truncated), the HSK3.0 level from the book (一①, 一②, 一③, 二, 三, or 附; and I include the word's index for reference), and the HSK2.0 level if relevant.  Collocations were sourced from [Collocation Search](http://cca.xingtanlu.cn/index.php) (and should reflect the most common use of the given measure word) unless marked by an asterisk.

---

## HSK3.0 measure words

#### [个](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%AA) (gè)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [2717]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /people or objects in general/
> 一个人   一个月   一个小时   一个字   一个孩子   一个星期   一个朋友   一个国家

#### [只](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%AA) (zhī)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [10473]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /birds and certain animals, one of a pair, some utensils, vessels etc/
> 一只手   一只猫   一只狗   一只船   一只眼睛   一只脚   一只老虎

#### [次](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AC%A1) (cì)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [1317]; HSK2.0: **2**
> /enumerated events: time/
> 一次机会   一次车   一次会议   一次面   一次经历

#### [种](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%A7%8D) (zhǒng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [10656]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /types, kinds, sorts/
> 一种方式   一种人   一种感觉   一种动物   一种方法   一种习惯

#### [家](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%B6) (jiā)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [3857]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /families or businesses/
> 一家公司   一家人   一家企业   一家餐厅   一家店   一家商店

#### [把](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8A%8A) (bǎ)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [78]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /objects with handle/small objects: handful/
> 一把椅子   一把伞   一把雨伞   一把双刃剑   一把钥匙

#### [两](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%A4) (liǎng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [5153]; HSK2.0: **2**
> /tael, unit of weight equal to 50 grams (modern)/
> 一两银子

#### [点](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%82%B9) (diǎn)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [1806]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /items/
> 一点菜   一点钱   一点东西   一点水   一点飞机

#### [分](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%88%86) (fēn)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [2333]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /part or subdivision/fraction/one tenth (of certain units)/unit of length equivalent to 0.33 cm/minute (unit of time)/minute (angular measurement unit)/a point (in sports or games)/0.01 yuan (unit of money)/
> 一分钱   一分货   一分价钱   一分饱

#### [元](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%83) (yuán)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [9989]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /currency unit (esp. Chinese yuan)/
> 一元钱   一元人民币   一元奖金   一元大奖

#### [名](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%90%8D) (míng)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [5631]; HSK2.0: -
> /people/
> 一名大学生   一名学生   一名妇女   一名志愿者   一名留学生

#### [张](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BC%A0) (zhāng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [10254]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /flat objects, sheet/votes/
> 一张照片   一张桌子   一张票   一张地图   一张纸   一张床

#### [回](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9B%9E) (huí)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [3567]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /acts of a play/
> 一回事   一回事儿   一回好汉

#### [行](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%A1%8C) (háng)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [3204]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /row/line/
> 一行字

#### [件](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BB%B6) (jiàn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [3989]; HSK2.0: **2**
> /events, things, clothes etc/
> 一件事   一件事情   一件衣服   一件衬衫   一件毛衣   一件礼物

#### [双](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%8C) (shuāng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [7540]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /pair/
> 一双鞋   一双眼睛   一双筷子   一双皮鞋   一双人间   一双袜子   一双手   一双儿女

#### [岁](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B2%81) (suì)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [7731]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /years (of age)/
> 一岁时   一岁时候

#### [套](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A5%97) (tào)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [7865]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /sets, collections/
> 一套房子   一套公寓   一套西服   一套衣服   一套程序   一套沙发

#### [句](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%A5) (jù)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4511]; HSK2.0: -
> /phrases or lines of verse/
> 一句话   一句俗话   一句名言   一句诗   一句歌词

#### [条](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9D%A1) (tiáo)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [7982]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /long thin things (ribbon, river, road, trousers etc)/
> 一条路   一条腿   一条裤子   一条裙子   一条胡同   一条河   一条鱼   一条街   一条狗

#### [场](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9C%BA) (cháng)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [855]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /classifer for events and happenings/
> 一场灾难   一场病   一场京剧   一场招聘会   一场雨   一场电影   一场运动   一场雪   一场球   一场考试

#### [头](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A4%B4) (tóu)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [8108]; HSK2.0: -
> /pigs or livestock/
> 一头牛   一头老牛   一头骆驼   一头驴   一头大象   一头毛驴   一头河马   一头水   一头黑熊

#### [本](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9C%AC) (běn)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [304]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /books, periodicals, files etc/
> 一本书   一本词典   一本杂志   一本小说   一本字典

#### [位](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BD%8D) (wèi)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [8434]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /people (honorific)/binary bits (e.g. 十六位 16-bit or 2 bytes)/
> 一位朋友   一位老人   一位老师   一位先生   一位姑娘

#### [所](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%80) (suǒ)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [7750]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /houses, small buildings, institutions etc/
> 一所大学   一所学校   一所小学   一所中学   一所医院   一所房子

#### [首](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A6%96) (shǒu)

> HSK3.0: **二** [7416]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /poems, songs etc/
> 一首诗   一首歌   一首词   一首歌曲   一首民歌   一首曲子   一首乐曲

#### [号](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%B7) (hào)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [3252]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /classifier used to indicate number of people/
> 一号嘉宾

#### [份](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BB%BD) (fèn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2377]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /gifts, newspaper, magazine, papers, reports, contracts etc/variant of 分[fen4]/
> 一份工作   一份报告   一份文件   一份礼物   一份遗嘱   一份报纸

#### [段](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AE%B5) (duàn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2009]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /stories, periods of time, lengths of thread etc/
> 一段时间   一段话   一段经历   一段路   一段故事   一段时期   一段历史   一段相声   一段长城   一段日子

#### [片](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%89%87) (piàn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [6092]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /slices, tablets, tract of land, area of water/CDs, movies, DVDs etc/used with numeral 一[yi1]: scenario, scene, feeling, atmosphere, sound etc/
> 一片叶子   一片土地   一片面包   一片空白   一片树林   一片笑声

#### [度](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BA%A6) (dù)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [1993]; HSK2.0: -
> /events and occurrences/
> 一度电

#### [部](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%83%A8) (bù)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [655]; HSK2.0: -
> /works of literature, films, machines etc/
> 一部电影   一部小说   一部书   一部著作   一部作品   一部机器   一部电视剧

#### [滴](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%BB%B4) (dī)

> HSK3.0: **二** [1742]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /a drop/
> 一滴水   一滴眼泪   一滴泪   一滴泪珠

#### [块](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9D%97) (kuài)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [4841]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /lump (of earth)/chunk/piece/pieces of cloth, cake, soap etc/(coll.) money and currency units/
> 一块钱   一块石头   一块糖   一块土地   一块人民币   一块饼干   一块地   一块手表   一块空地   一块蛋糕

#### [些](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BA%9B) (xiē)

> HSK3.0: **二** [8946]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /classifier indicating a small amount or small number greater than 1: some, a few, several/
> 一些日子   一些东西   一些钱   一些药   一些水果   一些礼物

#### [声](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A3%B0) (shēng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [7156]; HSK2.0: -
> /sounds/
> 一声巨响

#### [台](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%B0) (tái)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [7777]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /vehicles or machines/
> 一台电脑   一台电视   一台电视机   一台彩电   一台计算机   一台笔记本   一台拖拉机   一台洗衣机

#### [包](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8C%85) (bāo)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [176]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /bundle/packet/
> 一包烟   一包东西   一包药   一包饼干

#### [米](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%B1%B3) (mǐ)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [5557]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /meter (classifier)/
> 一米处   一米地方   一米速度

#### [口](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%A3) (kǒu)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [4787]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /things with mouths (people, domestic animals, cannons, wells etc)/bites or mouthfuls/
> 一口气   一口人   一口井   一口锅   一口家   一口水   一口钟   一口小锅   一口普通话   一口汉语

#### [面](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%9D%A2) (miàn)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [5585]; HSK2.0: -
> /flat surfaces such as drums, mirrors, flags etc/
> 一面镜子   一面墙上   一面墙

#### [秒](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%A7%92) (miǎo)

> HSK3.0: **二** [5609]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /second (unit of time)/
> 一秒钟

#### [座](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BA%A7) (zuò)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [11081]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /buildings, mountains and similar immovable objects/
> 一座城市   一座山   一座桥   一座大山   一座楼   一座城   一座山峰   一座古城   一座小山   一座建筑

#### [颗](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A2%97) (kē)

> HSK3.0: **二** [4700]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /small spheres, pearls, corn grains, teeth, hearts, satellites etc/
> 一颗心   一颗星星   一颗珍珠   一颗种子   一颗星   一颗牙齿   一颗杏子   一颗牙   一颗原子弹

#### [篇](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AF%87) (piān)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [6089]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /written items: chapter, article/
> 一篇文章   一篇论文   一篇报道   一篇小说   一篇课文   一篇作文   一篇短文   一篇日记   一篇报告

#### [班](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%8F%AD) (bān)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [123]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /groups/
> 一班飞机   一班火车 (*)

#### [期](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9C%9F) (qī)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [6213]; HSK2.0: -
> /issues of a periodical, courses of study/
> 一期杂志   一期款子 (*)

#### [集](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%9B%86) (jí)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3770]; HSK2.0: -
> /sections of a TV series etc: episode/
> 一集电视剧 (*)

#### [顶](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A1%B6) (dǐng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [1877]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /headwear, hats, veils etc/
> 一顶帽子   一顶毡帽

#### [间](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%97%B4) (jiān)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [3923]; HSK2.0: -
> /rooms/
> 一间屋子   一间房子   一间房   一间卧室   一间正房   一间小屋   一间房间

#### [则](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%88%99) (zé)

> HSK3.0: **三** [10180]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /written items/
> 一则广告   一则故事

#### [门](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%97%A8) (mén)

> HSK3.0: **一①** [5519]; HSK2.0: **2**
> /large guns/lessons, subjects, branches of technology/
> 一门课   一门艺术   一门学问   一门手艺   一门学科   一门外语   一门功课   一门科学

#### [群](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%BE%A4) (qún)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [6661]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /group/crowd/flock, herd, pack etc/
> 一群人   一群孩子   一群羊   一群骆驼

#### [道](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%81%93) (dào)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [1675]; HSK2.0: -
> /long thin things (rivers, cracks etc), barriers (walls, doors etc), questions (in an exam etc), commands, courses in a meal, steps in a process/(old) circuit (administrative division)/
> 一道菜   一道题   一道难题   一道风景   一道命令   一道门

#### [毛](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AF%9B) (máo)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [5451]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /Chinese fractional monetary unit ( = 角[jiao3] , = one-tenth of a yuan or 10 fen 分[fen1])/
> 一毛钱

#### [堆](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A0%86) (duī)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2016]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /pile/heap/stack/
> 一堆人   一堆砖   一堆垃圾

#### [顿](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A1%BF) (dùn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2055]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /meals, beatings, scoldings etc: time, bout, spell, meal/
> 一顿饭   一顿晚饭   一顿饺子   一顿美餐

#### [类](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%B1%BB) (lèi)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [5004]; HSK2.0: -
> /kind/type/class/category/
> 一类人   一类学生   一类东西   一类父亲   一类事情   一类国道   一类商品

#### [枚](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9E%9A) (méi)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5484]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /coins, rings, badges, pearls, sporting medals, rockets, satellites etc/
> 一枚硬币   一枚奖章   一枚卫星 (*)

#### [瓶](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%93%B6) (píng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [6168]; HSK2.0: -
> /wine and liquids/
> 一瓶啤酒   一瓶水   一瓶饮料   一瓶可乐   一瓶酒   一瓶汽水儿   一瓶矿泉水   一瓶空气   一瓶红葡萄酒   一瓶酸奶

#### [克](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%8B) (kè)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4732]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /gram/
> 一克水 (*)

#### [支](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%94%AF) (zhī)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [10463]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /rods such as pens and guns, for army divisions and for songs or compositions/
> 一支烟   一支箭   一支笔   一支曲子   一支玫瑰   一支卫队   一支钢笔   一支蜡烛   一支歌   一支喜烟

#### [辆](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%BE%86) (liàng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [5165]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /vehicles/
> 一辆车   一辆自行车   一辆汽车   一辆出租车   一辆轿车

#### [排](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8E%92) (pái)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [5961]; HSK2.0: -
> /lines, rows etc/
> 一排书架   一排旗帜 (*)

#### [斤](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%96%A4) (jīn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4257]; HSK2.0: -
> /(PRC) weight equal to 500 g/(Tw) weight equal to 600 g/(HK, Malaysia, Singapore) slightly over 604 g/
> 一斤钱   一斤香蕉   一斤肉   一斤苹果   一斤猪肉   一斤白酒

#### [项](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A1%B9) (xiàng)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [8862]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /principles, items, clauses, tasks, research projects etc/
> 一项调查   一项指标   一项原则   一项工程   一项任务   一项内容   一项运动   一项国策   一项技术   一项结果

#### [盘](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%9B%98) (pán)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5982]; HSK2.0: -
> /food: dish, helping/to coil/coils of wire/games of chess/
> 一盘菜   一盘饺子   一盘棋   一盘豆腐

#### [页](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A1%B5) (yè)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [9455]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /page/leaf/
> 一页书   一页纸

#### [餐](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A4%90) (cān)

> HSK3.0: **二** [711]; HSK2.0: -
> /meals/
> 一餐三明治   一餐饭菜 (*)

#### [根](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A0%B9) (gēn)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2735]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /long slender objects, e.g. cigarettes, guitar strings/
> 一根柱子   一根竹竿   一根头发   一根小棍儿   一根绳子

#### [轮](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%BD%AE) (lún)

> HSK3.0: **二** [5362]; HSK2.0: -
> /big round objects: disk, or recurring events: round, turn/
> 一轮满月   一轮明月 (*)

#### [番](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%95%AA) (fān)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2186]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /occurrences (of an event, action or speech utterance)/iterations: times, -fold (as in twofold etc)/situations: kind, sort/
> 一番话   一番道歉   一番结婚纪念日 (*)

#### [封](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B0%81) (fēng)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2420]; HSK2.0: -
> /sealed objects, esp. letters/
> 一封信   一封邮件   一封回信   一封电报   一封信件   一封情书

#### [笔](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AC%94) (bǐ)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [353]; HSK2.0: -
> /sums of money, deals/
> 一笔钱   一笔财富   一笔遗产   一笔收入   一笔资金

#### [团](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9B%A2) (tuán)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [8175]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /a lump or a soft mass: wad (of paper), ball (of wool), cloud (of smoke)/
> 一团火

#### [股](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%82%A1) (gǔ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2904]; HSK2.0: -
> /long winding things like ropes, rivers etc/smoke, smells etc: thread, puff, whiff/bands of people, gangs etc/sudden forceful actions/
> 一股力量   一股味儿   一股邪气   一股清香   一股浪潮   一股暖流

#### [节](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%8A%82) (jié)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4182]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /segments, e.g. lessons, train wagons, biblical verses/
> 一节课   一节车厢

#### [公里](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%AC%E9%87%8C) (gōnglǐ)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2797]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /kilometer/
> 一公里处   一公里长

#### [届](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B1%8A) (jiè)

> HSK3.0: **二** [4244]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /events, meetings, elections, sporting fixtures, years (of graduation)/
> 一届运动会   一届任期

#### [趟](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B6%9F) (tàng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [7840]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /times, round trips or rows/
> 一趟车   一趟家   一趟航班

#### [阵](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%98%B5) (zhèn)

> HSK3.0: **二** [10370]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /events or states of short duration/
> 一阵清风   一阵炮火 (*)

#### [样](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A0%B7) (yàng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [9390]; HSK2.0: -
> /classifier: kind, type/
> 一样东西   一样菜   一样食品   一样花   一样点心

#### [副](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%89%AF) (fù)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2520]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /pairs, sets of things & facial expressions/
> 一副对联   一副样子   一副眼镜   一副模样   一副墨镜   一副耳机   一副手套   一副象棋   一副春联

#### [角](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%A7%92) (jiǎo)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4102]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /unit of money equal to 0.1 yuan, or 10 cents (a dime)/
> 一角钱

#### [朵](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9C%B5) (duǒ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2083]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /flowers, clouds etc/
> 一朵花   一朵红花   一朵浪花

#### [架](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9E%B6) (jià)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [3899]; HSK2.0: -
> /planes, large vehicles, radios etc/
> 一架飞机   一架机器

#### [批](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%B9) (pī)

> HSK3.0: **二** [6052]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /batches, lots, military flights/
> 一批货   一批人   一批志愿者   一批知识分子   一批产品   一批留学生   一批货物

#### [盒](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%9B%92) (hé)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3312]; HSK2.0: -
> /small box/case/
> 一盒月饼   一盒蛋糕   一盒牛奶   一盒罐头   一盒录音带   一盒饼干   一盒茶叶

#### [卷](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8D%B7) (juàn)

> HSK3.0: **二** [4545]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /small rolled things (wad of paper money, movie reel etc)/
> 一卷书

#### [粒](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%B2%92) (lì)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5100]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /small round things (peas, bullets, peanuts, pills, grains etc)/
> 一粒米   一粒纽扣   一粒药 (*)

#### [桩](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A1%A9) (zhuāng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [10827]; HSK2.0: -
> /items/
> 一桩事 (*)

#### [码](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%A0%81) (mǎ)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5407]; HSK2.0: -
> /length or distance (yard), happenings etc/
> 一码路 (*)

#### [幅](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B9%85) (fú)

> HSK3.0: **二** [2468]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /textiles or pictures/
> 一幅画   一幅图画   一幅画儿   一幅山水画   一幅字   一幅中国画   一幅作品   一幅油画   一幅地图   一幅肖像

#### [箱](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AE%B1) (xiāng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [8832]; HSK2.0: -
> /box/trunk/chest/
> 一箱啤酒   一箱垃圾   一箱橘子 (*)

#### [棵](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A3%B5) (kē)

> HSK3.0: **二** [4699]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /trees, cabbages, plants etc/
> 一棵树   一棵大树   一棵草   一棵苹果树   一棵茶树   一棵白菜   一棵杨树   一棵树上   一棵花生病

#### [壶](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A3%B6) (hú)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3417]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /bottled liquid/
> 一壶酒   一壶茶

#### [厘米](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8E%98%E7%B1%B3) (límǐ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [5024]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /centimeter/
> 一厘米面积 (*)

#### [局](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B1%80) (jú)

> HSK3.0: **二** [4482]; HSK2.0: -
> /games: match, set, round etc/
> 一局比赛 (*)

#### [串](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%B2) (chuàn)

> HSK3.0: **二** [1248]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /things that are strung together, or in a bunch, or in a row: string of, bunch of, series of/
> 一串珍珠   一串钥匙 (*)

#### [列](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%88%97) (liè)

> HSK3.0: **二** [5182]; HSK2.0: -
> /trains, motorcade, columns/
> 一列火车

#### [栋](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A0%8B) (dòng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [1951]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /houses or buildings/
> 一栋楼   一栋房子   一栋楼上

#### [户](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%88%B7) (hù)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3430]; HSK2.0: -
> /a household/door/family/
> 一户人家   一户家庭   一户居民

#### [缕](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%BC%95) (lǚ)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5343]; HSK2.0: -
> /wisps (of smoke, mist or vapor), strands, locks (of hair)/
> 一缕头发   一缕烟   一缕云 (*)

#### [盏](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%9B%8F) (zhǎn)

> HSK3.0: **附** [10225]; HSK2.0: -
> /lamps/
> 一盏灯

#### [截](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%88%AA) (jié)

> HSK3.0: **三** [4211]; HSK2.0: -
> /section/chunk/length/
> 一截绳子   一截粉笔 (*)

#### [摊](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%91%8A) (tān)

> HSK3.0: **三** [7799]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /paste or think liquid/
> 一摊血   一摊泥 (*)

#### [枝](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9E%9D) (zhī)

> HSK3.0: **二** [10477]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /sticks, rods, pencils etc/
> 一枝笔   一枝箭   一枝玫瑰

#### [公斤](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%AC%E6%96%A4) (gōngjīn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [2793]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /kilogram (kg)/
> 一公斤咖啡   一公斤西红柿 (*)

#### [胎](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%83%8E) (tāi)

> HSK3.0: **三** [7775]; HSK2.0: -
> /litter/
> 一胎政策

#### [束](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9D%9F) (shù)

> HSK3.0: **一③** [7500]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /bunches, bundles, beams of light etc/
> 一束鲜花   一束花   一束花儿

#### [艘](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%89%98) (sōu)

> HSK3.0: **三** [7682]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /ships/
> 一艘船

#### [堂](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%A0%82) (táng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [7832]; HSK2.0: -
> /classes, lectures etc/sets of furniture/
> 一堂课

#### [立方](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AB%8B%E6%96%B9) (lìfāng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5080]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /cube (math.)/
> 一立方公尺   一立方英里 (*)

#### [尺](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B0%BA) (chě)

> HSK3.0: **二** [1041]; HSK2.0: -
> /a Chinese foot/one-third of a meter/
> 一尺宽 (*)

#### [伙](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BC%99) (huǒ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3659]; HSK2.0: -
> /groups of people/
> 一伙人   一伙罪犯 (*)

#### [匹](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8C%B9) (pǐ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [6073]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /horses, mules etc/
> 一匹马   一匹骏马   一匹千里马   一匹小马

#### [平方米](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E7%B1%B3) (píngfāngmǐ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [6137]; HSK2.0: -
> /square meter/
> 一平方米玻璃 (*)

#### [剂](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%89%82) (jì)

> HSK3.0: **三** [3821]; HSK2.0: -
> /dose (medicine)/
> 一剂药

#### [毫升](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AF%AB%E5%8D%87) (háoshēng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3219]; HSK2.0: -
> /milliliter/
> 一毫升水   一毫升血 (*)

#### [亩](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BA%A9) (mǔ)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5714]; HSK2.0: -
> /fields/
> 一亩地   一亩良田 (*)

#### [磅](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%A3%85) (bàng)

> HSK3.0: **附** [175]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /(loanword) pound/
> 一磅牛肉   一磅豌豆 (*)

#### [宗](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%97) (zōng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [10954]; HSK2.0: -
> /batches, items, cases (medical or legal), reservoirs/
> 一宗寿司   一宗抢劫案 (*)

#### [株](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A0%AA) (zhū)

> HSK3.0: **三** [10698]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /trees or plants/
> 一株树 (*)

#### [担](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8B%85) (dàn)

> HSK3.0: **三** [1595]; HSK2.0: -
> /loads carried on a shoulder pole/
> 一担水   一担柴火 (*)

#### [幢](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B9%A2) (zhuàng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [10845]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /buildings/
> 一幢楼   一幢房子

#### [毫米](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AF%AB%E7%B1%B3) (háomǐ)

> HSK3.0: **二** [3218]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /millimeter/
> 一毫米雨量 (*)

#### [平方](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9) (píngfāng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [6136]; HSK2.0: **5**
> /square (as in square foot, square mile, square root)/
> 一平方毫米 (*)

#### [立方米](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AB%8B%E6%96%B9%E7%B1%B3) (lìfāngmǐ)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5081]; HSK2.0: -
> /cubic meter (unit of volume)/
> 一立方米泥土 (*)

#### [公顷](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%AC%E9%A1%B7) (gōngqǐng)

> HSK3.0: **三** [2804]; HSK2.0: -
> /hectare/
> 一公顷森林 (*)

#### [千克](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8D%83%E5%85%8B) (qiānkè)

> HSK3.0: **二** [6320]; HSK2.0: -
> /kilogram/
> 一千克米   一千克黄油 (*)

#### [捆](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8D%86) (kǔn)

> HSK3.0: **三** [4881]; HSK2.0: -
> /bundle/
> 一捆劈柴   一捆树枝 (*)

---

I left off some from the list that are different (but still labeled as 量 in the book):

#### [下](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%8B) (xià)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [8679]; HSK2.0: **1**
> /measure word to show the frequency of an action/

#### [成](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%88%90) (chéng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [954]; HSK2.0: -
> /percent/

#### [刻](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%88%BB) (kè)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [4736]; HSK2.0: **3**
> /short time intervals/

#### [遍](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%81%8D) (biàn)

> HSK3.0: **一②** [421]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /actions: one time/

#### [倍](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%80%8D) (bèi)

> HSK3.0: **二** [293]; HSK2.0: **4**
> /(two, three etc) -fold/

#### [章](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%AB%A0) (zhāng)

> HSK3.0: **二** [10259]; HSK2.0: -
> /chapter/section/clause/movement (of symphony)/

#### [人次](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BA%BA%E6%AC%A1) (réncì)

> HSK3.0: **三** [6702]; HSK2.0: -
> /number of people participating/

#### [摄氏度](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%91%84%E6%B0%8F%E5%BA%A6) (Shèshìdù)

> HSK3.0: **三** [7051]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /°C (degrees Celsius)/

#### [马力](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A9%AC%E5%8A%9B) (mǎlì)

> HSK3.0: **三** [5401]; HSK2.0: -
> /horsepower/

#### [丸](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%B8) (wán)

> HSK3.0: **三** [8286]; HSK2.0: **6**
> /ball/

---

The following arise in the HSK2.0 and/or HSK3.0 vocabularies, and are considered measure words in CC-CEDICT, but are not listed as measure words in the aforementioned book:

> 付 令 任 册 出 刀 剑 发 口子 听 和 响 喷 圈 堵 处 孔 季 层 席 床 扇 手 扎 折 抹 挂 挺 文 方 服 杆 杯 枪 标 档 棒 水 泡 注 火 环 画 眼 票 窝 管 纸 组 绞 缸 脚 记 贴 起 转 辈 进 通 造 领 骑